# Remove Airbnb results that require upload of ID

Tags: safety, airbnb, privacy

Based on [Can I use Airbnb without trusting them with my ID?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152463/can-i-use-airbnb-without-trusting-them-with-my-id) it seems some landlords require ID and that this may be the reason Airbnb asks for ID.

Is there a way I can filter the results, so I only get results that do not require upload of ID?

(Before you ask why I refuse to share a copy of my ID-card, read [Can I use Airbnb without trusting them with my ID?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152463/can-i-use-airbnb-without-trusting-them-with-my-id))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible on Airbnb.com to remove results that require upload of ID.